# What open source photo library/database system can I use to build my website?

Tags: open-source, photo-management, web

I'm planning a web-based searchable photo database. Any suggestions for what software to use? I've seen stockbox. I want an opensource community content management system, with the potential to add customised functions and fields to the database.

Comment: Seems less of a photo question and more of a software question.

Comment: It may be something other photographers have done even if it's not strictly related to the act of taking photos. Even you don't get an answer here, you could try posting to http://doctype.com/ which is an affiliated site for web design questions!

Comment: Can you be more specific about your needs? Would [Gallery](http://gallery.menalto.com) work for what you want to do?

Comment: I consider it to be on topic, at least to the extent of gathering answers of where to start looking.

Comment: Would be on topic at https://softwarerecs.stackexchange.com if you described more explicitly your needs.

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend building it using WordPress using some of the custom photo gallery templates which are available.Lot of sites allow one click installs for word press and then you can easily load a custom plugin on to it.Here are some plugins to consider :

http://chasesagum.com/8-cool-wordpress-photo-gallery-plugins

Another alternative is using Drupal but I wouldnt recommend it unless you have some prior programming experience.

Comment: I think something like https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ResourceSpace might be more what he is looking for